# Untraceability of Virtual Machine

Tags: virtualization

I'd like to know if it is possible to set a Virtual Machine as a protection against traceability.
I would want my traffic to be impossible (or hard) to link to my current computer.

I guess that the specific element that ties a traffic to a machine (namely, a person) is the MAC adress.
Thus, I thought that with a Virtual Machine, it would become much harder to tie a specific person to a specific traffic.

Is this assumption correct ?

**EDIT :** Rephrased, sorry for unclearness

Comment: Untraceable for who?  When doing what?

Comment: Do you want your traffic to be untraceable to your location? Do you want your identity to be untraceable as opposed to your usual machine? Do you want your VM to not look like a VM?

Comment: MAC address is not readable outside your local network, so that's not a concern. MAC addresses can also be spoofed to the local network.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely nothing is "completely untraceable." You can hide your identity with proxies, tor, VPN etc.. but it is still very easy to out yourself.

Answer (score 2):

First: MAC address don't mean anything outside of the local network.

If you use bridge, the MAC of the virtual machine **will** be sent to the local network, but not on the Internet (like every MAC: real, virtual or faked). If you use NAT, the virtual MAC will not exist outside of your computer.

However, the virtual machine can leak data about the physical machine under special circunstances. If you read the [Security chapter on VirtualBox site](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch13.html), you will see some recomendations about this.

A virtual machine can be *reasonably* secure if you follow the rules ([those are good rules](https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Security_Guide)), but to be completely untraceable you will have to disconnect the physical host from the internet.